# SDWebImage, Swift: SDWebImageRefreshCached unresolved identifier

Tags: swift, sdwebimage

Strange.. something simple that is in the docs doesn't seem to work with Swift.  See below code.  Where exactly is "SDWebImageRefreshCached" when using Swift??

```
self.profileImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(profileImageUrl, placeholderImage:  UIImage(named: "default_profile_image"), options: SDWebImageRefreshCached)
```

Answer (score 7):

In Swift, the enums are exposed slightly differently.

You would be looking for `SDWebImageOptions.RefreshCached`, or `.RefreshCached` for short.

Your line of code thus would be:

```
self.profileImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(profileImageUrl, placeholderImage:  UIImage(named: "default_profile_image"), options: .RefreshCached)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

.RefreshCached is change to .refreshCached in SDWebImage 4.0.0

```
//SDWebImage 4.0.0
self.profileImageView.sd_setImage(with: yourImageUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage("Your placeholder image name"), options: .refreshCached)
```